# Django: how to create groups?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication

**EXAMPLE** to elaborate my problem -> I am the user of the website and i want to **create** a **group**. While creating group the website **asked me** the **group_name,group_description ,group_password (as i don't want the group to be public and a person if want to join the group should know the password)**. now i have given the name and the password to my friends and they can **join** the group by **authenticating** with the **password** of group to successfully **join**.

**ISSUE** i am facing -> i have created the password field in **models.py**. But the password is saved in the database as plane text but not something liked hashed django passwords. secondly, i want in the joining user to authenticate with the password in order to join the group.

models.py

```
class Group(models.Model):
admin = models.ForeignKey(to=Profile, related_name="admin", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
password = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='thinkgroupy')
slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True)
group_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="users/group_images/%y/%m/%d",null=True)
about = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
about_html = models.TextField(editable=False, default='', blank=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="GroupMember")

def __str__(self):
    return "%s" % self.name

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.name)
    self.about_html = misaka.html(self.about)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("groups:single", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

class Meta:
    ordering = ["name"]


class GroupMember(models.Model):
group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name="memberships")
user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='user_groups')

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username

class Meta:
    unique_together = ("group", "user")
```

views.py

```
 class CreateGroup(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
        fields = ("name", "description","password")
        model = Group

class JoinGroup(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return reverse("groups:single",kwargs={"slug": self.kwargs.get("slug")})
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        group = get_object_or_404(Group,slug=self.kwargs.get("slug"))
        try:
            GroupMember.objects.create(user=self.request.user,group=group)
        except IntegrityError:
            messages.warning(self.request,("Warning, already a member of {}".format(group.name)))
        else:
            messages.success(self.request,"You are now a member of the {} group.".format(group.name))
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```